# can I script to mount a drive to a mountpoint in windows

Tags: windows, script, mount

My windows server guy created a mountpoint drive for me, such as drive letter E for my SQL Server database files.  I can use Disk Management in Computer Management from Administrative Tools to map a standard directory, such as D:\SQL\data\ServerName\MP1, to the mountpoint letter E.  I can do it manually without problems.  I am wondering if there is a windows script way to do it in a script, so that I do not have to do it manually using Disk Management's GUI.

Any suggestion is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is probably [net use](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490717.aspx). It allows mounting shared locations to the specified drive letters, amongst other things.

Answer (score 0):

You can right click "My Computer" and select "map network drive" from the context menu.
This will bring up a dialog box that will allow you to assign the drive letter and path.  You can type in the path or browse for it.  There are also a checkboxes that allow you to automatically reconnect at logon, as well as save your credentials.